# ERROR: role "test" does not exist - in PL/pgSQL code block

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I am unable to think as to why this would fail. The block commands should work if it meets the condition?
On version 14.6

```
postgres# DO
postgres# $do$
postgres# DECLARE
postgres#   lc_db_names CONSTANT text[] := array['dev3','dev2','dev1'];
postgres# BEGIN
postgres#   IF current_database() = any(lc_db_names)
postgres#   THEN
postgres#  IF NOT EXISTS (
postgres#    SELECT FROM pg_catalog.pg_roles WHERE  rolname = 'test') THEN
postgres#    create role test login encrypted password 'md5d2cdf586595c9e1ca7c7d7db3951f3fd';
postgres#    create schema authorization test;
postgres#    execute format('grant connect, temporary on database %I to %I', current_database(), 'test');
postgres#  END IF;
postgres#   END IF;
postgres# END
postgres# $do$
postgres# ;

ERROR:  role "test" does not exist
CONTEXT:  SQL statement "grant connect, temporary on database postgres to "test""
PL/pgSQL function inline_code_block line 11 at EXECUTE
```

Comment: 1) FYI, in `psql` if you do `\s` you get the command history that you can copy and paste from without the prompts e.g. `postgres#`. 2) What does the Postgres log show when you run this command? 3) Does the role `test` exist?

Comment: the above script creates the role test though. Its running in sequence. The issue may be in the script itself (i think)

Comment: The error 'ERROR:  role "test" does not exist` says it does not. So again provide the answers to 2) and 3) Does  `\du` show 'test'?

Comment: the log does not shed any more light than the errors stated there. No the role test does no exist

Comment: if i remove ```execute format('grant connect, temporary on database %I to %I', current_database(), 'test');```  the script works

Comment: It works for me here on Postgres 14 and 15.

Comment: The dynamic `GRANT` command would only be executed if `current_database() = any(lc_db_names)`, but the error msg reveals database "postgres" (the default maintenance DB), which is not in `lc_db_names`. Does not add up. The error message cannot be produced by the displayed `DO` command.